# Change Variant property-names (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, mormot

I'm learning a great framework mORMot for Delphi, and I found plenty of useful functions to handle with `Variant` (in SynCommons).

Now I want to change some property-names of a `Variant`, but after a search I have not found such a function, so I decide to write one:

```
program Project7;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, SynCommons;

function VariantChangeNames(var V: Variant; const FromNames, ToNames: TRawUTF8DynArray): Boolean;
var
  Name: RawUTF8;
  PData: PDocVariantData;
  Val: Variant;
  i, k: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  PData := DocVariantData(V);
  i := 0;
  for Name in FromNames do
  begin
    k := PData^.GetValueIndex(Name);
    if k <> -1 then
    begin
      Val := PData^.Value[k];
      PData^.Value[ToNames[i]] := Val;
      PData^.Delete(k); // If delete before setting value, Val will be incorrect.
      Result := True;
    end;
    Inc(i);
  end;
end;

var
  V: Variant;
begin
  V := TDocVariant.New();
  V.Name := 'John';
  V.Age := 20;
  VariantChangeNames(V, ['Name'], ['RealName']);
  Writeln(VariantToString(V)); // {"Age":20,"RealName":"John"}
end.
```

`VariantChangeNames` I wrote may not be very efficient since it needs to do both `delete` and `add`. It seems that directly modify the `VName` member of the `TDocVariantData` is the most efficient way, but it's a private member.

Any advice? Thanks in advance.

BTW: The mail server of mORMot official forum seems to have a problem, when I post a topic, it shows:

```
An error was encountered
Error: Could not connect to smtp host "217.70.184.11" (111) (Connection refused).
```

Comment: I'm curious as to how people like to give a down vote without leaving any reason.
It's not helpful for help the questioner to improve his question next time.

Comment: You cannot create new variables with variants.  You can only use existing variable names. .... Even with RTTI you cannot create new data structures  (I think).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't want to change the variable names, but property-names in a Variant. You know a type of Variant can has properties, like an object. @Benedikt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was solved in [mORMot forum](https://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=4451).